# What is a NameError and how can I fix it?

Tags: python

I have defined a function to return the indices of certain occurrences in a list. However, when I try to run my doctests, it returns a NameError, but exits with 'exit code 0' meaning there's no problems with it.

```
def build_placements(shoes):
    """Return a dictionary where each key is a company, and each value
    is a list of placements by people wearing shoes made by that company.

    >>> result = build_placements(['Saucony', 'Asics', 'Asics', 'NB', 'Saucony', 'Nike', 'Asics', 'Adidas', 'Saucony', 'Asics'])
    >>> result == {'Saucony': [1, 5, 9], 'Asics': [2, 3, 7, 10], 'NB': [4], 'Nike': [6], 'Adidas': [8]}
    True
    """
    empty_dict = {}
    for item in shoes:
        indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(shoes) if x == item]
        for value in item:
            value += 1
        empty_dict[item] = indices
    return empty_dict


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

After running this, I get this error message:

```
NameError: name 'result' is not defined
```

I don't understand what part of my code is causing this.

Comment: I don't see any `result` in your code.

Comment: @Bazingaa It's in the doc-test.

Comment: Then you should include the complete code which reproduces the error

Comment: @Bazingaa The complete code ***is*** in the question - but the full traceback isn't. I suspect the `NameError` is just a side-effect of other errors in the code.

Comment: @ekhumoro: I see. The answer below addresses the concern I guess

Comment: Did you try the verbose mode? Try calling your script with the `-v` option, you'll get a detailed log which may help you to understand what is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```
for value in item:
    value += 1
```

`item` is an element of the `shoes` list, all elements of `shoes` are strings. You cannot add an integer to a string. So `value += 1` raises an error, and because of this the whole function fails. You never get a `return` variable. From here the error.

At first glance, you don't need those two lines at all, you never use `value` after. Try to remove them.

**EDIT**

If the meaning behind those lines was to increase each index value by 1, as I suspect from the docstring (thanks @ekhumoro to make me realize this), you can just edit the list comprehension to achieve the intended goal.

```
indices = [i+1 for i, x in enumerate(shoes) if x == item]
```

Comment: The first part of your answer is right, but you are wrong to say the second test is useless, since It correctly compares the expected result with the output of the function. If the off-by-one bug is fixed, the original doctest will in fact succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a shorter one

```
def build_placements(shoes):
    """Return a dictionary where each key is a company, and each value
    is a list of placements by people wearing shoes made by that company.

    >>> result = build_placements(['Saucony', 'Asics', 'Asics', 'NB', 'Saucony', 'Nike', 'Asics', 'Adidas', 'Saucony', 'Asics'])
    >>> result == {'Saucony': [1, 5, 9], 'Asics': [2, 3, 7, 10], 'NB': [4], 'Nike': [6], 'Adidas': [8]}
    True
    """
    return {i:[j+1 for j,k in enumerate(shoes) if k == i] for i in set(shoes)}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

this was produced

```
Trying:
    result = build_placements(['Saucony', 'Asics', 'Asics', 'NB', 'Saucony', 'Nike', 'Asics', 'Adidas', 'Saucony', 'Asics'])
Expecting nothing
ok
Trying:
    result == {'Saucony': [1, 5, 9], 'Asics': [2, 3, 7, 10], 'NB': [4], 'Nike': [6], 'Adidas': [8]}
Expecting:
    True
ok
1 items had no tests:
    __main__
1 items passed all tests:
   2 tests in __main__.build_placements
2 tests in 2 items.
2 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

Comment: The `>>>`s are the whole point of using the `doctest` module. While this solves the issue it completely disregards the intention of the OP.

Comment: Thanks @FynnBecker